# Error inserting data into sqlite3 table Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a table called entities in sqlite3 as shown below.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('entities_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entities')
cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE entities (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tweet_id INTEGER, type TEXT, 
        value INTEGER, start_index INTEGER, end_index INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (tweet_id) REFERENCES tweets (id))
''')
conn.close()
```

I have a list called type_list, and it contains several lists of data. A part of the data is shown below

```
type_list = [
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["user_mentions", "urls", "media"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["hashtags", "media"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["urls", "media"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["hashtags", "urls", "media"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
    ["hashtags", "urls"],
]
```

I would like to insert the data from type_list into the column "type" in my entities table, such that first row of that column will be the first list in type_list, second row will be the second list in type_list etc. I tried inserting using the method below

```
for v in type_list:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO entities (type) VALUES (?)', (v,))
```

However i came up with this error, InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: the entries in ` type_list` are `list` but type (in db) is defined as string. So how do you want to bridge this gap?

Comment: What about the `tweet_id`, `value`, `start_index`, `end_index` columns? What's your end goal here – why do you need exactly that data in your SQLite table?

Comment: as @balderman pointed out, you cannot store complex Python objects in the DB. You'd have so somehow serialize them. A common method would be to convert them to JSON. But if that's appropriate for your case only you can tell.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! @MikeScotty i converted the data to JSON and it works now. That was what i am looking for. I am new to this so thanks!